# laravel result array of array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this eloquent query

```
$data= \App\Logs::select('id', 'created_at') 
    ->get()         
    ->groupBy(function($val) {
        return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('d-M-');
    })->toArray();
```

and this retun something like that

```
array:2 [▼
  "06-Jul-" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "created_at" => "2017-07-06 13:21:15"
    ]
  ]
  "07-Jul-" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "created_at" => "2017-07-07 13:43:23"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "created_at" => "2017-07-07 14:18:36"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 4
      "created_at" => "2017-07-07 14:18:41"
    ]
  ]
]
```

and i want return just the count
"06-Jul-" => "1"
"07-Jul-" => "3"

how i can do that?

Comment: try this `\App\Logs::select('count(id) as count, 'created_at') ->groupBy('created_at')->toArray()`

Comment: Can you try `->only("id")` instead of `->toArray()`

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz if i use groupby ('created_at') i cant group by day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use/chain `map/transform` after your `groupBy` for example:

```php
$data = \App\Logs::select('id', 'created_at') 
->get()         
->groupBy(function($val) {
    return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('d-M-');
})
->transform(function ($collection, $key) {
    return $collection->count();
});
```